# Cucumber Java Maven - ExtendedCucumberOptions - Features missing steps

Tags: java, maven, cucumber-junit, runner

I'm facing the next behavior when I run my Runner class in IntelliJ.

This is the pipeline of my project:

```
src
|_main
|_test
  |_java
    |_runners
      |_TestRunner
    |_stepdefs
      |_ServiceHooks
      |_StepDefinitionsCafest
  |_resource
    |_features
      |_Cafest.feature
```

This is my Runner Class:

```
import com.github.mkolisnyk.cucumber.runner.ExtendedCucumber;
import com.github.mkolisnyk.cucumber.runner.ExtendedCucumberOptions;
import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

@RunWith(ExtendedCucumber.class)
@ExtendedCucumberOptions(
        jsonReport = "target/cucumber-reports/CucumberTestReport.json",
        retryCount = 3,
        detailedReport = true,
        detailedAggregatedReport = true,
        overviewReport = true,
        coverageReport = true,
        jsonUsageReport = "target/cucumber-reports/cucumber-usage.json",
        usageReport = false,
        toPDF = true,
        excludeCoverageTags = {"@flaky" },
        includeCoverageTags = {"@passed" },
        outputFolder = "target/cucumber-reports/extended-report")

@CucumberOptions(
        features =  {"src/test/resource/features"},
        glue=       {"src/test/java/stepdefs"},
        monochrome = true,
        tags =      {"~@Ignore"},
        plugin =    {
                    "html:target/cucumber-reports/cucumber-html-report",
                    "pretty:target/cucumber-reports/cucumber-pretty",
                    "json:target/cucumber-reports/CucumberTestReport.json",
                    "rerun:target/cucumber-reports/rerun.txt"}
        )

public class TestRunner {
}
```

I don't know if it is neccesary, but here is my POM:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>cl.cooper</groupId>
    <artifactId>automation_test_cukes</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <cucumber.version>1.2.5</cucumber.version>
        <java.version>8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- CUCUMBER DEPENDENCIES -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-jvm-deps</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.5</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.5</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.5</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.5</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.mkolisnyk</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-runner</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.3</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.mkolisnyk</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-report-generator</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.3</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- CUCUMBER DEPENDENCIES -->
        <!-- SELENIUM DEPENDENCIES -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-ie-driver</artifactId>
            <version>3.12.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-support</artifactId>
            <version>3.12.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>2.53.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- SELENIUM DEPENDENCIES -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.stephenc.monte</groupId>
            <artifactId>monte-screen-recorder</artifactId>
            <version>0.7.7.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>3.17</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>22.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.21.0</version>
                <configuration>
                       <includes>
                            <include>TestRunner.java</include>
                        </includes>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.7.0</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>8</source>
                        <target>8</target>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
        <reporting>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-report-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.21.0</version>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </reporting>
    </project>
```

When I run my Runner, it displays the next messages on screen:

```
Test ignored.

Test ignored.
Scenario completed...0

3 Scenarios (3 undefined)
9 Steps (9 undefined)
0m0.000s


You can implement missing steps with the snippets below:

@Given("^...
```

I have tried with different ways to fix the issue, I have red about similar problems with runners in Cucumber, but I can't do anything else.
Could you please help me?

I already have implemented the step in their own classes, but the runner is not recognizing them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to Run it, for this I had to make the next changes in my dependencies (POM.xml):

Settled all the Cucumber dependecies in **1.2.5**: cucumber-jvm (instead of cucumber-jvm-deps), cucumber-junit, cucumber-java, cucumber-core.

The cucumber-runner and cucumber-report-generator to the **1.3.3** version

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>cl.cooper</groupId>
    <artifactId>automation_test_cukes</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <cucumber.version>1.2.5</cucumber.version>
        <java.version>8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- CUCUMBER DEPENDENCIES -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-jvm</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.5</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.5</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.5</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.5</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.mkolisnyk</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-runner</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.3</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.mkolisnyk</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-report-generator</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.3</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- CUCUMBER DEPENDENCIES -->
        <!-- SELENIUM DEPENDENCIES -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.12.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-ie-driver</artifactId>
            <version>3.12.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-support</artifactId>
            <version>3.12.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>2.53.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- SELENIUM DEPENDENCIES -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.stephenc.monte</groupId>
            <artifactId>monte-screen-recorder</artifactId>
            <version>0.7.7.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>3.17</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>22.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.21.0</version>
                <configuration>
                       <includes>
                            <include>runners.TestRunner.java</include>
                        </includes>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.7.0</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>8</source>
                        <target>8</target>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
        <reporting>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-report-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.21.0</version>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </reporting>
    </project>
```

By other hand, I made a little modifications to my Rummer class:

```
import com.github.mkolisnyk.cucumber.runner.ExtendedCucumber;
import com.github.mkolisnyk.cucumber.runner.ExtendedCucumberOptions;
import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

@RunWith(ExtendedCucumber.class)
@ExtendedCucumberOptions(
        jsonReport = "target/cucumber-reports/CucumberTestReport.json",
        retryCount = 3,
        detailedReport = true,
        detailedAggregatedReport = true,
        overviewReport = true,
        coverageReport = true,
        jsonUsageReport = "target/cucumber-reports/cucumber-usage.json",
        usageReport = false,
        toPDF = true,
        excludeCoverageTags = {"@flaky" },
        includeCoverageTags = {"@passed" },
        outputFolder = "target/cucumber-reports/extended-report")

@CucumberOptions(
        features =  {"src/test/resource/features"},
        glue=       {"stepdefs"},
        monochrome = true,
        tags =      {"~@Ignore"},
        plugin =    {
                    "pretty", "html:target/cucumber-reports/cucumber-html-report",
                    "json:target/cucumber-reports/CucumberTestReport.json",
                    "rerun:target/cucumber-reports/rerun.txt"}
        )

public class TestRunner {
```

I'm happy: This is the first time that I can run the Runner class with JUnit instead of TestNG runner.

Thanks for all!!!